# Replace Only Beginning DIV Tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to replace only the beginning DIV tag using jquery. I have the below code that works, but it replaces the whole DIV, beginning and ending tag, and I'm trying to apply it to a plugin and it is breaking it. I'm not sure how to only replace the `<div class="cycle-slideshow">` and not `<div class="cycle-slideshow"></div>`

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow">
    Text Text Text Text
</div>

<script>
 $("div.cycle-slideshow-new-class").each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith( "<div class='cycle-slideshow'>" + $(this).html() + "</div>" );
});
</script>
```

Comment: try adding html structure so people can see what you're talking about

Comment: there's no such thing as a `<div class='cycle-slideshow'>` without a `</div>` once it's a dom node. You can't replace part of something that can't be broken apart.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to change the classname on the div, so just do that `$(this).attr('class','whatever')` instead of trying to rewrite the html of the element.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `.className` `"cycle-slideshow-new-class"`, add `.className` `"cycle-slideshow"`

```
 $("div.cycle-slideshow-new-class").each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("cycle-slideshow-new-class")
    .addClass("c‌​ycle-slideshow");
 });
```

or the opposite

```
 $("div.cycle-slideshow").each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("cycle-slideshow")
    .addClass("c‌​ycle-slideshow-new-class");
 });
```

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
var elem = $("div.cycle-slideshow-new-class:first");
$("div.cycle-slideshow-new-class:first").removeClass("cycle-slideshow-new-class").addClass("cycle-slideshow").html(elem.html)
```